# Suggestions for new sliding glass tub/shower door

Tags: bathroom, shower

I'm working on a bathroom remodel, and looking to replace the old nasty sliding glass door with a new glass door. Problem is the tile only goes half way up the wall (about 32"), so there'd be a 1/2" gap along the top part of the wall. Any suggestions on how to close the gap with a new door? The original just looks like some strips of sheet metal and caulk and looks really bad.
[image]

[image]